# uWSGI raises OSError: write error during large request

Tags: python, nginx, uwsgi

My application uses nginx, with uWSGI on the server side. When I do a large request (with a response time > 4s), the following appears:

```
SIGPIPE: writing to a closed pipe/socket/fd (probably the client
    disconnected) on request _URL_ (ip XX.XX.XX.XX) !!!

uwsgi_response_writev_headers_and_body_do(): Broken pipe
    [core/writer.c line 287] during GET _URL_ (XX.XX.XX.XX)

OSError: write error
```

It seems that uWSGI tries to write in a stream but this stream has already been closed.
When I check nginx log (error.log):

```
upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response
    header from upstream ...
```

Of course, my client (REST client or browser) receives a 502 error.

I always get this error after ~4s.

However, I don't know how to prevent this issue.
I tried to set some parameters in my nginx config file:

```
location my_api_url {
    [...]
    uwsgi_buffer_size 32k;
    uwsgi_buffers 8 32k;
    uwsgi_busy_buffers_size 32k;

    uwsgi_read_timeout 300;
    uwsgi_send_timeout 300;

    uwsgi_connect_timeout 60;
}
```

But the issue is still here.
I also tried to set these parameters in the uWSGI configuration file (wsgi.ini):

```
buffer-size=8192
ignore-sigpipe=true
ignore-write-errors=true
```

Before to try to optimize the response time, I hope this issue has a solution. I don't find one that's working in another post. I work with a large amount of data, so my response time, for some case, will be between 4-10s.

Hope you can help me :)

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Is you NGINX behind a proxy or something? Usually write error occurs when client closed the connection preemptively.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

It may be the case that when you upload things, you use chunked encoding.
There is uWSGI option
[`--chunked-input-timeout`](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Options.html#chunked-input-timeout),
that by default is 4 seconds (it [defaults](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Chunked.html#options)
to value of `--socket-timeout`, which is 4 seconds).

Though problem theoretically may lie somewhere else, I suggest you to try
aforementioned options. Plus, annoying exceptions are the reason why I have

```
ignore-sigpipe=true
ignore-write-errors=true
disable-write-exception=true
```

in my uWSGI config (note that I provide 3 options, not 2):

- `ignore-sigpipe` makes uWSGI not show SIGPIPE errors;
- `ignore-write-errors` makes it not show errors with
  e.g. `uwsgi_response_writev_headers_and_body_do`;
- `disable-write-exception` prevents
  `OSError` generation on writes.

Comment: Thanks! Really helpul answer!

Comment: Note that `ignore-sigpipe`, `ignore-write-errors` and `disable-write-exception` should be provided without arguments as per the uWSGI latest version. See https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Options.html

Comment: To replicate the errors on regular (not large) requests, open up a page on your uWSGI-powered site and hammer on the F5 (refresh) key a few times rapidly. Very helpful for testing out the above config changes.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, Nginx as a backproxy of uwsgi, the config [http-timeout](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Options.html#http-timeout) set the server to normally wait in long running requests.

Mind that the following options included in the nginx proxy declaration:

```
proxy_read_timeout 300s;
proxy_connect_timeout 300s;
proxy_send_timeout 300s;
```

were doing **nothing** regarding the gateway timeout.

Answer (score 3):

I added `[socket-timeout=xxx]` in my `uwsgi.ini` config, it worked.

Comment: I don't have a uwsgi.ini file, I just run
`uwsgi --socket 0.0.0.0:8000 --protocol=http -w wsgi:application --enable-threads -H /home/test/env --daemonize /home/test/test.log` . In this case how do I set the socked-timeout?

Comment: To add this option in your command line, just add `--socket-timeout xxx`